# How add multiple capabilities to add_menu_page?

Tags: wordpress

I am writing a plugin and need to give access to "Subscriber" and "Administrator" only. I am writing this code

```
add_menu_page( 'Country Profiles', 'Country Profiles', 'subscriber', 'countryprofile', 'Adm_CountryProfile', '', 2 );
```

but this is giving access only to Subscriber, not Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

The `add_menu_page()` function is designed to take a capability, not a role. [See the documentation.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) So for administrator, you could do something like:

`add_menu_page('Country Profiles', 'Country Profiles', 'activate_plugins', 'countryprofile', 'Adm_CountryProfile', '', 2);`

since the admin is the only role with that capability by default. I don't know of any capabilities shared by the admin and subscriber only, so you'd need to create your own capability if that's a requirement. [See the documentation for add_cap().](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap) You can pass any string to this, for example, 'edit_country_profiles'.

If you're doing this all in a plugin, it's highly suggested to use `add_cap()` on plugin activation using [register_activation_hook().](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook)

Answer (score 0):

In a WP Multisite instance, a `Super Admin` should have access to other user's capabilities. You may want to consider upgrading from a single WP install. https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network?